# Facebook Messenger bot blocking server requests

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

So, I decided to move my PHP back-end to another server. The old server works just fine. I changed facebook settings, so that the webhooks point to the new server. The server receives messages just fine, webhooks work well, but it can't send the messages back.

CURL shows the following error:

```
*   Trying 157.240.1.18...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 157.240.1.18: Permission denied
* Closing connection 0
```

I have absolutely no idea why permission would be denied. I'm using correct tokents etc and I didn't use any blacklisting features.

Comment: What's your request look like?

Comment: I found the answer, the hosting was blocking outgoing requests